# "Certify" vs. "certificate"

Tags: word-choice, differences

As verbs, what are the differences and relation between *certify* and *certificate*?

For example, in human resources, why is it *effort certify* not *effort certificate*?

Answer (score 2):

"Certify" is a verb, "certificate" is a noun. You would issue a "certificate of effort" if you were to "certify effort".

Using "certificate" (long a there) as verb is an error, I would say. The listener will understand what you're saying, but it falls under the same heading as "orientate" (as opposed the shorter identical verb "orient"), in my estimation.

Comment: http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/certificate_2

Comment: Interesting...this must be a British English neologism. Appropriately enough, the "orientate" example is also primarily a BE formation.

Comment: So, to put a bow on my answer - their meanings are identical, and the "certificate" usage is found primarily in British English, which seems to enjoy these formations.

Comment: I'm British but I've never heard certificate as a verb; it sounds wrong. Human resources departments don't have a great track record in their use of English.

Comment: @Hugo - Amen on the HR comment...this may be some kind of new corporate-speak like "performant" or "incentivize".

Comment: I wonder what the followings mean: (1) "a long A"; (2) "put a bow on something"?

Comment: "Long A" means "the sound in English which rhymes with the name of the letter", so "A" is in "rate", or "fate", and not as in "rat" or "fat". When you put a bow on a present, it is the final step which adds nothing functional to the equation, but organizes and enhances the presentation.

Comment: @Chris programmers use "performant" and find it a perfectly satisfactory word ("tending to perform (well)"), but "incentivize" galls: it is used as if it meant "to offer an incentive" when it seems like it should mean "to cause to become an incentive" (and how, exactly, would one do that to anything?).

Comment: Yeah, I'm a programmer and I use "performant" :). I was playfully chastised about it once, so it stuck in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Certify** has a bit more variability to it in my opinion.  [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certify) offers "to inform with certainty".  In this sense it may be used to simply mean *confirm*, *assure*, *verify*, etc. (A friend recently asked me, "Could you certify that he is a reliable man?")  In other cases it could also mean *allow*, especially in computer contexts.

Meanwhile, **certificate** would almost always mean to grant a certificate, or at the least to decree something in an outright official manner.

As for me, I would never use the latter.  It sounds a bit too much like business jargon to be taken seriously in my mind.